# how to change (-) to NA

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a dataset that uses (-) for NA cells how can I change all - to NA in the data frame.

I have imported numpy

I have used the following code but that doesn't work.

```
dash_to_na = data_df.replace('-',np.nan)
```

Comment: That works. Could you show your data? ` - ` might be having spaces?

Comment: "It does not work" is not an acceptable description of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The best option might be to read your data in with

```
df = pd.read_csv('<filename>', na_values='-')
```

Comment: that returns the previous - as NAN no NA

Comment: @john ? NaN is what pandas uses for NA / NaN.